# Finiteness of difference $( K\exp(xn) - \exp(x(n+1)) )^+$

Tags: real-analysis

As I am trying to improve my basic math skills, I struggle to proof that for fixed $K$, I can find an $n \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$, such that for all $x\in \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ the difference

$$(~K\exp(xn) - \exp(x(n+1)) ~)^+$$

is bounded.

Intuitively, its clear because $\exp(n+1)$ should outweigh $\exp(n)$ for high powers of $n$. Though its hard for me to compute explicitly the lower/upper bounds.

Comment: Is the $+$ supposed to be $x$?

Comment: no, the + means for 2 values x,y : $(x-y)^+ = max(x-y, 0)$

Comment: Well then your expression doesn't depend on $x$ at all...

Comment: Sorry, I had an format mistake. I have corrected it accordingly.

Comment: Hint: you can write $e^{(n+1)x}$ in terms of $e^{nx}$ and $e^x$ using the standard rules for exponentiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any $n$ at all will work.  Note that $$K\exp(xn) - \exp(x(n+1))=K\exp(xn)-\exp(xn)\exp(x)=\exp(xn)(K-\exp(x)).$$  For $x$ sufficiently large, $K-\exp(x)<0$, so the entire expression will be negative, and $(K\exp(xn) - \exp(x(n+1)))^+$ will be $0$.  So you only need to bound $K\exp(xn) - \exp(x(n+1))$ for $x\in[0,N]$ for some $N$, and this follows from compactness of $[0,N]$ and continuity of $x\mapsto K\exp(xn) - \exp(x(n+1))$.

Comment: Thank you. I am just curious, is it possible to write down an explicit upper bound in the sense of the def. of wikipedia:
$Kexp(xn)−exp(x(n+1)) \leq C$

Comment: Also i have a second question concerning the first part of your answer.
Why do you distinguish the reasoning based on the sign of $K -\exp(x)$ ?
Using the compactness and continuity argument should work in either way?

Comment: A third question arises: Can i conclude that 
$(K \exp(xn)− \exp(x(n+1)) )^+$ is not in $L^1$, because the integral
$\int_{\mathbb{R}} (K \exp(xn)− \exp(x(n+1)) )^+ dx$ is not finite, since you relied on the finiteness of $x$?